# Basic Setup of Postfix/dovecot failing with "status=deferred"

Tags: email, postfix

I've tried to set up email on a VPS by following the [Linode Guide](http://library.linode.com/email/postfix/postfix-dovecot-mysql-ubuntu-10.04-lucid) for doing so, but I've gotten to the end where I sent a test email, and its failing.

When I check `/var/log/mail.log` I see the following:

> Jun 23 03:49:01 li115-209
>   postfix/pipe[9769]: 95FEAA6B0:
>   to=, relay=dove
>   cot, delay=1024,
>   delays=1024/0.02/0/0.01, dsn=4.3.0,
>   status=deferred (temporary failure)

I've double checked to make sure I've entered the domain name and email recipient correctly in mySQL. I'm not sure where to go from here in order to get working email.

Thanks for any help.

### Edit: @ grufftech

```
Jun 23 03:31:57 li115-209 postfix/pickup[9709]: 95FEAA6B0: uid=0 from=<root>
Jun 23 03:31:57 li115-209 postfix/cleanup[9721]: 95FEAA6B0: message-id=<20100623033157.95FEAA6B0@li115-209.members.linode.com>
Jun 23 03:31:57 li115-209 postfix/qmgr[9710]: 95FEAA6B0: from=<root@li115-209.members.lineode.com>, size=455, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 23 03:31:57 li115-209 postfix/pipe[9727]: 95FEAA6B0: to=<first@medetis.com>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.04, delays=0.03/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (temporary failure)
Jun 23 03:39:01 li115-209 postfix/qmgr[9710]: 95FEAA6B0: from=<root@li115-209.members.lineode.com>, size=455, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 23 03:39:01 li115-209 postfix/pipe[9755]: 95FEAA6B0: to=<first@medetis.com>, relay=dovecot, delay=424, delays=424/0.02/0/0.07, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (temporary failure)
Jun 23 03:49:01 li115-209 postfix/qmgr[9710]: 95FEAA6B0: from=<root@li115-209.members.lineode.com>, size=455, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 23 03:49:01 li115-209 postfix/pipe[9769]: 95FEAA6B0: to=<first@medetis.com>, relay=dovecot, delay=1024, delays=1024/0.02/0/0.01, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (temporary failure)
Jun 23 04:09:01 li115-209 postfix/qmgr[9710]: 95FEAA6B0: from=<root@li115-209.members.lineode.com>, size=455, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 23 04:09:01 li115-209 postfix/pipe[9786]: 95FEAA6B0: to=<first@medetis.com>, relay=dovecot, delay=2224, delays=2224/0.02/0/0.01, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (temporary failure)
```

### Can Send Out Email

Also tested to make sure that outgoing email performed properly - sent something to my yahoo account via mailx and while it got autosorted to spam, it did show up.

### update 2

Been trying to find a solution, stumbled on dovecot-deliver.log which shows:

```
2010-06-23 04:59:01 deliver(first@medetis.com): Error: Namespace 'INBOX.': Mail storage autodetection failed with home=/home/vmail/medetis.com/first
2010-06-23 04:59:01 deliver(first@medetis.com): Fatal: Namespace initialization failed
```

but I haven't the foggiest what this means I need to fix.

Comment: Can you cat the mail.log | grep 95FEAA6B0 so we can see the entire email, and hopefully a specific error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are relaying to dovecot, is it possible you're trying to do the mysql mailbox method in dovecot where you don't have a physical home directory for the users?  If that is the case, it appears your virtual transport isn't set up correctly.

The 1024 second delay looks curiously odd - almost as if postfix is not connecting to your server and timing out.  I remember at one point postfix had an issue with localhost versus 127.0.0.1, and if you use 127.0.0.1, you need to make sure your database has given grants to dbuser@127.0.0.1.

Comment: granted access to the 'mail' database to mail_admin@127.0.0.1 and sent another test mail with the same results.

Comment: If you have your system configured to require a valid reverse DNS entry, you have misspelled linode.com in your mailname

Comment: @aaa: fixed the incorrect FQDN but that hasn't fixed the problem. I'm sure it saved me grief down the road.

Comment: turn on mysql logging, restart mysql, restart postfix -- what queries are executed if any?  If you are connecting to mysql, it should be issuing some queries or loops.  What does mailq report?  Sometimes it is a little more detailed.

Comment: mailq only reports 'temporary failure'. mysql logging reports mail_admin@localhost connecting and issuing 3 queries for a mail from the tables forwardings, users, and domains which is what I expected from reading the step-by-step setup. ALSO: found my first hint as to what may be wrong, but not sure what it means. See edit above.

Comment: mail_location = maildir:/home/vmail/%d/%n    /home/vmail needs to be owned by the same user/gid specified in your master.cf

 dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
    flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -d ${recipient}

well, that pasted poorly.  Hopefully you can comprehend the lack of whitespace and formatting.

Comment: `/home/vmail` is owned by `user:vmail, group:vmail` already. Is that what you meant? I'm not quite quite sure what the code you pasted is about though, you could edit your answer if its important.

Comment: Also; in dovecot.conf the line is `args = uid=5000 gid=5000 home=/home/vmail/%d/%n allow_all_users=yes` so i think that's set up correctly

Comment: I love the hidden grey/3 more comments.  Did Paul Graham design the color scheme for this?

That error message means that you are missing mail_location = maildir:/home/vmail/%d/%n   Either the maildir: or mbox: designator is missing depending on how you are setting up your email and since there is no previously delivered mail, dovecot doesn't know how to handle it.

Comment: I eventually figured out what that part of your comment meant, and yes it fixed the problem straight away. Thank you so very much.